# Change Android BottomBar Icon on Select

Tags: android, android-navigation, bottombar

Is there an easy way to change the icon for the Android `BottomBar` navigation (https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar). I have seen a number of ways to set this icon, but I would like to change the icon when the user selects it. Currently I have an icon, with outline, and I would like to display a filled icon when they select it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the guys at `BottomBar` decided to incorporate this. They added the ability in 2.2.0:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_myicon_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_myicon_default" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

You can find the reference [here](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar#changing-icons-based-on-selection-state).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a getter and setter for the `iconResId` in the source file.
Have you given that a go?

Create an object of BottomBarTab() and call this setter method in the OnItemSelected with your desired icon choice.
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/bottom-bar/src/main/java/com/roughike/bottombar/BottomBarTab.java#L175

Comment: Well, that's strange.
I'd suggest opening an issue on github as the author would know what's the best way to do it.

Comment: I did. Lol... I'm hoping to hear something back soon.